# How does Android Studio/IntelliJ decide on iml file names?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I've got a weird problem that I'd like to get to the bottom of. I have a number of modules within Android studio, of the structure:

```
core/
  modules/
    module1
    module2
    module3
    ...
```

They all have roughly identical `build.gradle` files and are set up identically. When I  do a fresh import of this project, Android Studio generates iml files for each of these modules. However, for some reason, roughly half the modules get files named like `module1.iml`, while the other half get files named like `core-modules-module2.iml`. This makes it somewhat difficult to find the appropriate `build.gradle` file within Android Studio.

Does anyone know where this difference is coming from? I see that it's consistent with the `modules.xml` file in `.idea`, but this issue persists when I delete `.idea`, delete all `.iml` files, and then re-import, so the names must be getting generated somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle based modules IDE names the module namy according to Gradle conventions - by default it is the directory path relative to project root.

> This makes it somewhat difficult to find the appropriate build.gradle file within Android Studio.

Why is this related to module names? You can identify the module when open each build.gradle file in the tab name:

[image]